# ¿Significado del doble guión bajo "__" en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, get, set, props, underscorejs

Abro esta pregunta porque he consultado algunas respuestas y estaban orientadas a Python. A mi me gustaría saber qué hace un doble guión bajo `__` en JavaScript.

Por ejemplo:

```
const obj = {
  get prop() {
    return this.prop;
  },
  set prop(value) {
    this.prop = value * 2;
  },
};

obj.prop = 12;

console.log(obj.prop); //Return error
```

Esta ejemplo anterior da error. Sin embargo, el siguiente funciona:

```
const obj = {
  get prop() {
    return this.__prop__;
  },
  set prop(value) {
    this.__prop__ = value * 2;
  },
};

obj.prop = 12;

console.log(obj.prop); // Return 24
```

¿Qué ocurre? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No significan nada en particular, lo único que haces es cambiar el nombre de la propiedad `prop`, porque en el primer caso al intentar obtener `obj.prop` haces que el *getter* se llame a sí mismo recursivamente hasta el infinito, de ahí el error.

Comment: @juanrpozo bien visto. Te animo a que lo redactes como respuesta para así dar por respondida la pregunta.

Comment: Te recomiendo esta publicación. [Why some attribute names start with double underscore in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547293/why-some-attribute-names-start-with-double-underscore-in-javascript)

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestras aclaraciones. Un saludo!